# How can I dynamically read XML files in a folder without refreshing my app using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, io

I have an application where I am loading XML files in a specific folder.  I would like to automatically pick up any new XML files placed in a specific folder without refreshing or restarting my app.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It allows you to monitor a specific directory and get an event when a file is created/changed/deleted